# Matching a pattern in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a below input file which contains:

```
000ABCDEFGHIJKLMN2018022623595900021
CGT11~|~|110~|~|221~|~|H0331~|~|~|~|
CGT11~|~|110~|~|222~|~|H0332~|~|~|~|
CGT11~|~|110~|~|223~|~|H0335~|~|~|~|
CGT11~|~|110~|~|224~|~|H0333~|~|~|~|
99800000000000000011~|~|~|~|~|~|~|~|
```

I want to count the no of lines and go to the last line of the file and check "999". If it matches then it will proceed to the next step or else it will throw an error message. Currently the last line of my input file is having "998" so it will throw an error message. How can i do this in Perl. Can someone help me in resolving the issue?

My current code is having below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(FILE, "<deep.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";

my $lines = 0;

while (<FILE>) {
    $lines++;
if($Number =~ m/\d{1,3}/){

     $N = $Number;
print "$N";
 }
}

print "The no of lines present is $lines \n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure, but this might help

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fname = "deep.txt";
open(my $fh, "<:encoding(ASCII)", $fname) || die "cannot open $fname for reading";

my $num = 0;

while(<$fh>)
{
    $num = substr $_, 0, 3 if eof;
}
close($fh) || warn "cannot close $fname";

print "Oops, last line doesn't start with 999!\n" if $num != 999;
```

The `eof` check helps to know if it is the last line of file being read

The while loop can also be shortened to one-line:

```
eof and $num = substr $_, 0, 3 while(<$fh>);
```

Further reading:

- https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Opening-Text-Files
- https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html
- https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html

Comment: @DeepMukherjee glad it worked :) see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and imo, you should ask perl questions on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'END { if ($0 !~ /^999/) print "error"; else printf("Lines in file: %d\n", NR) }' file
```

If the last line of the file does not start with `999` the string `error` will be displayed. Otherwise the number of lines in the file will be displayed in a short message.

The same thing with Perl:

```
perl -ne '$line=$_; END { if ($line !~ /^999/) { print "error\n" } else { printf "Lines in file: %d\n", $. } }' file
```

The script (beautified):

```
$line = $_;

END {
    if   ( $line !~ /^999/ ) { print "error\n" }
    else                     { printf "Lines in file: %d\n", $. }
}
```

This sets `$line` to the current line of input.

The `END` block is executed when no further input is available.  It tests whether the last `$line` begins with `999` or not and either prints an error or the number of lines.  The `$.` variable is a special Perl variable that corresponds to `NR` in `awk` (the number of lines/records read).